# Terminating asynchronous NSURLConnection loading prematurely

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsthread

I'm making an app that loads data asynchronously for a data picker, then reloads the data picker, and everything's fine.

The problem is that if the user taps on the text field, the app makes the network request for the info, but if it hasn't loaded and then the user taps the back button, then the view disappears, but the data is still loading in the background.

I've tried running this loading method on a custom thread and then calling `[myThread cancel];` on `viewWillDisappear`, but the data still loads. I want to avoid the user using data when he cleary doesn't want to load it anymore. Any help?

I was thinking of killing com.apple.nsurlconnectionloader but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note here, canceling an NSThread will not terminate it immediately, it will only mark it for termination.

What I would do instead is implement your `NSURLConnection` delegates within an `NSOperation`, and when you want to cancel your download you can call `cancel` on the operation, which will set its `isCanceled` property to `YES`. You can then use this as a flag to terminate the operation's runloop, and the download will not continue.

Apple has an excellent technote on using NSOperation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2109/_index.html

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your reply. 
I have a greater problem at hand then, see I have about 8 different ViewControllers that use a single class, i call it ServerInterface.h and .m, to connect to the server. For example myArray = [ServerInterface getAppointmentsForUser:1]; But since the NSURLConnection implements is async, I'd hace to implement the delegate methods in each of my classes instead of calling ServerInterface, right? Hope I am clear... :s

Comment: not really, you can just use ServerInterface in your NSOperation subclass, and make the operation the NSURLConnection's delegate. Basically, you would only have to implement the NSURLConnection delegates in one place: inside your NSOperation subclass. Check the URL in my answer for an Apple NSOperation tutorial